# How to I make this stop?

Tags: python

Right now, it reads off a txt file and gives me the sum per line. The problem is that it will print a line per line of numbers in my txt file (So say I my txt file has 25 different numbers, it will print "The accumulated total is:" 25 times, adding the last value to the next. I want only to print the total (one line). This is for a homework assignment.

```
def main ():
    print()
    print("This will add together the numbers on number.txt")
    print()
    total, error = getsum()

    if not error:
        total = getsum()
        print ("The sum is", total)

def getsum ():
    error = False
    total = 0
    try:
        infile = open("Numbers.txt", "r")
        line = infile.readline()

        while line != "":
            readnum = float(line)
            total = readnum + total
            line = infile.readline()

        print("The accumulated total is", total)            

       file.close()

    except IOError:
        print ("ERROR")
        error = True
    except ValueError:
        print ("ERROR")
        error = True

    if error:
        sum5 = 0
    else:
        sum5 = total
    return total, error, thesum

main ()
```

Comment: Please review your indentation

Comment: talking about the try function? Fixed.

Comment: Please edit your question so that the title is more descriptive. Also, your wording isn't clear which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: Hopefully I explained my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

```
print sum(map(float,filter(lambda line:line.strip(),open("some.txt"))))
```

is much shorter ... or if you are concerned baout not closing the file

```
with open("some.txt") as f:
     print sum(map(float,filter(lambda line:line.strip(),f)))
```

Comment: `filter` is superfluous when iterating over the file - a file iterator nevers return an empty string. `sum(float(line) for line in f)` is probably the most idiomatic, and avoids reading all the lines into memory.

Comment: Are you sure? I swear I've gotten empty strings from a file iterator with blank lines ...+1 if you're right

Comment: 100% sure - just try it.

Comment: ahh I see it still returns the "\n" ... fixing answer (at least in py2.6 ... which would raise an error if passed to float)

Comment: Note that the original code didn't filter out empty lines at all. It used `readline` to read individual lines, so testing for an empty line was how it checked for the EOF condition. Since your code uses the iterator version of line reading, it doesn't need that check at all.